# Content-based CSS grid stretches over width but not height

Tags: css, css-grid

In the example below, the `.grid-container` div will stretch over the width of the body (that is, the viewport width), but its height will be the same as the `.grid-item` height.

Any explanations to why that is the case? I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it.

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr / 1fr;
  place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">Grid item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Set `height: 100%;` on `.grid-container`

Comment: Grid container takes the height of it's content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading [MDN's display page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display), I think I found the answer:

> **grid** The element behaves like a **block** element and lays out its content according to the grid model.

The grid container by default behaves like a `block` element, which is why it will span the entire width of the parent when its size is not set explicitly. You can prevent this behavior and make it inline with `display: inline grid` or `display: inline-grid` (legacy).

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.grid-container {
  display: inline grid;
  grid-template: 1fr / 1fr;
  place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">Grid item</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr / 1fr;
  place-items: center;
  background-color: red;
}

.grid-item {
  
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">Grid item</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Grid item</div>
</div>
```

as you can see what you are doing here is not a grid. It would be better if you use CSS flexbox instead of grid for one column grid.
just replace this code with grid-container class

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
justify-items: space-around;
```

and also note that every element of type **div** in HTML takes the whole width of the line and it's height is defined by the content inside it. It doesn't stretch all the way down to the bottom until you set a fixed height to it. you can set `position: relative;` to grid container parent and set its position to `absolute`. then add `width: 100%;` and `height: 100%;` to it.

add more information about your code for more detailed help.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I only created one cell in this grid for simplicity, but what I'm saying would hold for something like `grid-template: 1fr 1fr / 1fr 1fr` and 4 grid items inside. 
As to the div, even when setting `display: inline-block` on it, the grid still takes the whole width of the page.

Comment: please provide the code for parent elements and tell us what exactly you want. your question is not clear.